# Table over two variables but ignore terms with common indices

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list of 1000 numbers called “sequence” and a function “dist” that calculates the distance between two numbers.

I am trying to create a table of distances between terms, but ignoring the terms

```
dist[sequence[[i]],sequence[[i]]]
```

for all $i$.

How can I change the code

```
Table[dist[sequence[[i]],sequence[[j]]],{i,1,1000},{j,1,1000}]
```

In order to ignore the distances between a term and itself?

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. You realize that the distance between points `i` and `j` will also be similar, whether it is `(i,j)` or `(j,i)` pair. As a (smaller example) try this: `sequence = RandomReal[{1, 10}, 10];` and `Table[a[i][j] = EuclideanDistance[sequence[[i]], sequence[[j]]], {i, 
   1, 10}, {j, 1, 10}] // Grid`. Try `a[3][2]` and `a[2][3]` : Substitute `dist` in this example.

Comment: @Syed I was thinking something like using $\{j,1,i-1\}$ for the second loop but that causes problems when $i=1$.

Comment: `(p = Table[
    a[i][j] = EuclideanDistance[sequence[[i]], sequence[[j]]], {i, 1, 
     10}, {j, 1, i - 1}]) // Grid` works ok. Also you can take a look at `SparseArray` since you matrix will be half-filled and has 1000 x 1000 entries.

Comment: @Syed But this includes  
    dist[sequence[[1]],sequence[[1]]] in the list no?

Comment: `(g = Table[
    a[i][j] = 
     If[i != j, EuclideanDistance[sequence[[i]], sequence[[j]]]], {i, 
     1, 10}, {j, 1, i}]) // Grid`

Comment: This feels like an XY problem. What is the intended us of this table?

Comment: @Alan just to have a list of the distances between distinct terms of the sequence. So that I can create a histogram if the different distances,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Response based on goals stated in comment:

```
n = 1000
seq = RandomReal[1, n];
distance = EuclideanDistance;
(* avoid i=j and duplicates *)
vals = Catenate@
   Table[distance[seq[[i]], seq[[j]]], {i, n}, {j, 1, i - 1}];
Histogram[vals]
```